# Is a single update statement with "where" transaction safe?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I understand that a single update statement is atomic, the row will be locked during update process. But when there is a "where" cause, is it still atomic?

For example:

```
table: ABC
-------------
|colA | colB|
-------------
|123  | 0   |

--update 1
update ABC set colA=456, colB=1 where colB=0;

--update 2
update ABC set colA=556, colB=2 where colB=0;
```

Due to the where cause, the update will first check colB value and find that row in the table, then lock the row for update, right?
If update 1 and update 2 is executed at the same time, is there a chance that both get successfully executed and one of them overwrite the value of another?

Is it better to write as below?

```
START TRANSACTION;
  update ABC set colA=456, colB=1 where colB=0;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 4):

*For sanity, we just assume inno*

> If update 1 and update 2 is executed at the same time, is there a chance that both get successfully executed and one of them overwrite the value of another?

No, that's not how MVCC works. And wrapping single statements in transactions doesn't do anything. They're effectively already wrapped in transactions.

The first transaction will read from ABC, lock it with a row-level lock pending update, write a new row with the updated value, and set it as live on the table.

The second transaction will read from ABC, if the row is locked, it'll block. If not, it will lock the row pending update, write a new row with the updated value, and set it to live on the new table. If it is locked, it'll wait until the lock releases and recheck the row.

Interestingly enough, the default isolation level of [read committed](https://www.pythian.com/blog/understanding-mysql-isolation-levels-repeatable-read/) does not protect from phantom writes. So if both transactions start at the same time, they'll both read from the same snapshot. But, if one txn1 writes the update it'll actually modify the snapshot txn2 is reading from. So while you can't read the modified data (phantom reads), when you try to write the data you're interacting with the same master copy.

Suggestion: [**Upgrade to a real database, if possible**](https://www.postgresql.org/)

For more information, read [the docs on MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/set-transaction/#read-uncommitted) on transaction isolation.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand "update" statement with a "where cause" is not safe.

Comment: Hi, would you answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838226/is-it-really-safe-that-running-update-t-set-v-v-1-where-v0-without-pessimisti

Answer (score 1):

(Evan's Answer stands; I want to point out something related.)

If you first look at the row before deciding to update it, do it this way:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  SELECT ... WHERE colB=0  FOR UPDATE;
  ... think about what to do
  UPDATE ... WHERE colB=0;
COMMIT;
```

With the `FOR UPDATE`, the row is locked earlier, thereby preventing the other transaction from grabbing the unchanged row, too.  This keeps you from possibly making the wrong decisions in the intervening rows.

In these simple examples, you may get a delay, but not a "deadlock".

Answer (score 0):

#### Conclusion

`UPDATE` statement with a simple `WHERE` clause is **SAFE**. Evan Carroll's answer is actually wrong. So the following queries can be safely executed at the same time.

```
-- Run by user A
update ABC set colA=456, colB=1 where colB=0;

-- Run by user B
update ABC set colA=556, colB=2 where colB=0;
```

#### Details

I've examined all possible conflicting patterns of the following queries.

- `UPDATE t SET v=v-1 WHERE id=1 AND v>0`
- `UPDATE t SET v=v-1 WHERE EXISTS(SUBQUERY)`

  - The subquery references `id`:1 of the row
- `UPDATE t SET v=(SUBQUERY)-1 WHERE id=1 AND v>0`

  - The subquery references `v` of the row which has `id`:1

[mpyw-yattemita/mysql-postgres-update-locking-and-isolation-levels](https://github.com/mpyw-yattemita/mysql-postgres-update-locking-and-isolation-levels)

> ### Postgres
>
> - **For simple updates or subquery `SET`, use `READ COMMITTED`.**
> - **For complex subquery `WHERE`, use `REPEATABLE READ` and retry on serialization errors.**
>
> |  | Simple | Subquery WHERE | Subquery SET |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | READ COMMITTED | ✅ | ❌ 5/6 Broken | ✅ |
> | REPEATABLE READ | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error |
> | SERIALIZABLE | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error | ❗ Serialization Error |
>
> #### Subquery WHERE with `READ COMMITTED` will be broken:
>
> | [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Act before A's commit | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
> | Act after A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
>
> ### MySQL
>
> - **For simple updates or subquery `SET`, any transaction isolation level works well.** `READ UNCOMMITTED` or `READ COMMITTED` are recommended.
> - **For complex subquery `WHERE`, use `REPEATABLE READ` and retry on deadlock errors.**
>
> |  | Simple | Subquery WHERE | Subquery SET |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | READ UNCOMMITTED | ✅ | ❌ 4/6 Broken | ✅ |
> | READ COMMITTED | ✅ | ❌ 5/6 Broken | ✅ |
> | REPEATABLE READ | ✅ | ❗ 1/6 Deadlock | ✅ |
> | SERIALIZABLE | ✅ | ❗ 1/6 Deadlock | ✅ |
>
> #### Subquery WHERE with `READ UNCOMMITTED` will be broken:
>
> | [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Act before A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
> | Act after A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
>
> #### Subquery WHERE with `READ COMMITTED` will be broken:
>
> | [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Act before A's commit | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
> | Act after A's commit | ✅ | ❌ Broken | ❌ Broken |
>
> #### Subquery WHERE with `REPEATABLE READ` will get deadlocks:
>
> | [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Act before A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
> | Act after A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ❗ Deadlock |
>
> #### Subquery WHERE with `SERIALIZABLE` will get deadlocks:
>
> | [B] Latter ＼ [A] Former | Before-Read Delay | Pre-Write Delay | Post-Write Delay |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Act before A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ❗ Deadlock |
> | Act after A's commit | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |